# Why does my C program not run even though it does not give an error?

Tags: c

I have just started learning programming in c. I have written a program that has an arithmetic sequence based on the number of arithmetic sequence sentences n.
The program will not work after 17 without giving me an error
I have tried several different ideas but I have not received an answer
Thank you for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int n ,k;
    float d ;
    printf("please write your arithmetic sequence sentences ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n");
    printf("please write your common differences");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("\n");
    printf("please write your initial element ");
    scanf("%f",&d);
    printf("error 1");
    printf("\n");
    printf("error 2");
    printf("number \t sum");
    printf("erorr 3");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (i < n)
        j = d + i*k;
        sum += j;
        printf("%d\t%d",j,sum);
        i++;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and the error is? and what are the input values?

Comment: @amir_su Use a compound statement as a sub-statement of the while loop. For example     while (i < n)
{
        j = d + i*k;
        sum += j;
        printf("%d\t%d",j,sum);
        i++;
}

Answer (score 2):

it is not python. You need to use `{}` to declare compound statement

```
    while (i < n)
    {
        j = d + i*k;
        sum += j;
        printf("%d\t%d\n",j,sum);
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: yes I forget use {} but Why line 17 of the program did not run (before starting the while loop)?